# Unable To Download MAC Os Build Option in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

Currently I am running Windows 10, Unity 2108.1.4f1, and I cannot find the Mac OS build option.[image]

When opening the correct installer for the 2108.1.4f1 build there was no option to select the Mac OS build support to install. So how do I install the build support for Mac OS?[image]

Comment: Select the "Mac Mono Scripting Backend" from your second screenshot then click next and it should install it. Restart Unity after that

Answer (score 1):

Use [Unity Hub](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta-download) - this is the new, preferred way to download Unity and it's components. Also supports multiple Unity versions at the same time

Best if you uninstall all standalone Unity versions before installing Unity Hub.

[image: Unity Hub]